# CakePHP: How to insert a row into a join table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two models/tables which have a "has and belongs to many" ([HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-habtm)) relationship: `Qsets` and `Questions`

I can delete rows manually as follows:

```
$this->Qset->QsetsQuestion->deleteAll( array("QsetsQuestion.qset_id"=>$qset_id, "QsetsQuestion.question_id"=>$question_id), false );
```

**How can I insert a new row in the join table?**
Any documentation I find for working with HABTM data refers specifically to forms, but my data isn't coming from a form.

Comment: Never heard of HABTM, but it sounds like a normal "Many to Many"  relationship.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-habtm

Comment: Then it's actually joining models and not tables ;)

Comment: What does "it" refer to?

Comment: it: "I have two models/tables which have a "has and belongs to many" (HABTM) relationship". When you're talking about tables from a database, it's called "Many to Many" and not "HABTM". You're talking about joining model relationships which has nothing directly to do with your table which makes your title misleading :P

Comment: This section of the docs talks about join table related to models. This might be helpful: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

It's something like this, I think:

```
$data = array(
    [Question] => Array
        (
            [id] => $question_id
        )
    [Qset] => Array
        (
            [id] => $qset_id
        )
);

$this->Question->saveAll($data);
```

Comment: Does it matter which controller I'm in when I do this? I tried it as you wrote it inside the QsetsController.php and it didn't work. I changed the last line to `$this->Qset->saveAll($data);` and it deleted all associations.

Comment: Aha! It works as you wrote it IF I add `Controller::loadModel('Question');` first.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use loadModel, in your Qsets controller this should work: $this->Qsets->Question->saveAll($data)

Comment: I'll try what you suggested. Can you briefly explain the difference between the two?

Comment: This `$this->Qsets->Question->saveAll($data);` causes this `Error: Call to a member function saveAll() on a non-object`

Comment: Do you have the HABTM setup in each model (Qsets/Question)? If you do I think the above should work.

Comment: I do have HABTM setup in each. Not sure why I have to load the model.

Comment: I can only suggest having another look - I quickly set up a test with two models, Blobs and Things, and a HABTM and from within the BlobsController this works fine: 

pr($this->Blob->Thing->find('all'))

Comment: I notice the first model is plural in your above example and singular in your last comment. I wonder if that's the problem